Insert row above totals and include row in formula range
I need to add a new row before a row with totals and include the new row in the formula range.
The code adds the row after the row with the totals.
Private Sub IncidentesFR_Open()
  Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
  Dim rng As Range, f As Range, r As Range  
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long, m As Long, d As Long
  Dim newRow As ListRow
  Dim cell As String
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
  Set sh1 = Sheets("Incidentes")
  Set sh2 = Sheets("Incidentes FR")
  
  n = sh1.ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Situation").Index
  
  Set r = sh1.Columns(n)
  Set f = r.Find("Out of the Rules2", , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False)
  If Not f Is Nothing Then
    cell = f.Address
    Do
      For j = 2 To sh2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row  '** I had put "B" in the range, but the correct one is "A"... but the problem continues
        If sh2.Range("A" & j).Value = "" Then
          Set newRow = sh2.ListObjects(1).ListRows.Add '*****  does the command to add the new row have to be indexed?
          sh1.Rows(f.Row).Copy sh2.Range("A" & j)
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
      Set f = r.FindNext(f)
    Loop While f.Address <> cell
  End If

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

How do I create a row in the correct position and change the formula range when the new row is added?


Your formulas should update but you should use table references.  Do you just want to append a row from  sh1.ListObjects(1) to sh2.ListObjects(1)`?  Please provide the table names.

188 is the total full generated by the ListObject?

@TinMan That's it 188, and the lines below, before adding the new line, are not part of my table, just total information... I need to insert the new line in this 188 position and the line with TOTAL 2024 has to go to position 189.

@TinMan My Table is not a dynamic table and its name is Table1345.

@Black cat It didn't work, I think you didn't understand what I want to do, the line with TOTAL 2024 must remain, and above it, I need to include the new line!... maybe I didn't understand your answer!!! Did you create this code in your Excel and it worked?... ...could you take a printout of your Excel screen to show me?

Append Rows from One Excel Table to Another



Private Sub IncidentesFR_Open()
  
    Const CRITERIA_STRING As String = "Out of the Rules2"
    Const SHOW_MESSAGE As Boolean = True
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' If it's not, use 'ActiveWorkbook' instead.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Incidentes")
    Dim slo As ListObject: Set slo = sws.ListObjects(1)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = slo.DataBodyRange.EntireColumn
    Dim scrg As Range:
    Set scrg = slo.ListColumns("Situation").DataBodyRange
    Dim scell As Range: Set scell = scrg.Find(CRITERIA_STRING, _
        scrg.Cells(scrg.Cells.Count), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
    
    Dim dRowsCount As Long
    If scell Is Nothing Then GoTo ProcExit
        
    Dim sFirstCellAddress As String: sFirstCellAddress = scell.Address
        
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Incidentes FR")
    Dim dlo As ListObject: Set dlo = dws.ListObjects(1)
    
    Dim dtcell As Range:
    Set dtcell = dlo.TotalsRowRange.Cells(dlo.ListColumns("Opened").Index)
    Dim dFormula As String: dFormula = dtcell.Formula
    Dim dPos As Long: dPos = InStr(dFormula, "(") + 1
    Dim dAddress As String: dAddress = Mid(dFormula, dPos, Len(dFormula) - dPos)
    Dim dtrg As Range: Set dtrg = dws.Range(dAddress)
    
    Dim drrg As Range:
    
    With dlo
        If .ListRows.Count = 0 Then
            Set drrg = .HeaderRowRange
        Else
            With .DataBodyRange
                Set drrg = .Rows(.Rows.Count)
            End With
        End If
    End With
    
    Do
        dRowsCount = dRowsCount + 1
        dlo.ListRows.Add
        srg.Rows(scell.Row).Copy Destination:=drrg.Offset(dRowsCount)
        Set scell = scrg.FindNext(After:=scell)
    Loop While scell.Address <> sFirstCellAddress
    
    If dRowsCount > 0 Then
        dtcell.Formula = Replace(dFormula, dAddress, _
            dtrg.Resize(dtrg.Rows.Count + dRowsCount).Address(0, 0))
    End If

ProcExit:
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    If SHOW_MESSAGE Then
        If dRowsCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No rows containing """ & CRITERIA_STRING & """ found.", _
                vbExclamation
        Else
            MsgBox dRowsCount & " row" & IIf(dRowsCount = 1, "", "s") _
                & " containing """ & CRITERIA_STRING & """ copied.", _
                vbInformation
        End If
    End If
            
End Sub


Thaks, your code and it worked!

when I run the code, in the line Set dtcell = dlo.TotalsRowRange.Cells(dlo.ListColumns("Opened").Index), the message appears: The object variable or With block variable is not defined.

This mod of your code insert the row to the end of the table.
To get the proper count of the rows in the table remove the TOTAL 2024 line from your table

Table tool -> Resize and decrement the last row with one.
=CONT.VALUES("$B$187:B187")

Maybe the english names different (my excel is not that)
 Private Sub IncidentesFR_Open()
  Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
  Dim rng As Range, f As Range, r As Range
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long, m As Long, d As Long
  Dim newRow As ListRow
  Dim cell As String
  
  'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
  Set sh1 = Sheets("Incidentes")
  Set sh2 = Sheets("Incidentes FR")
  
  n = sh1.ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Situation").Index
  
  Set r = sh1.Columns(n)
  Set f = r.Find("Out of the Rules2", , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False)
  If Not f Is Nothing Then
    cell = f.Address
    Do
      'For j = 2 To sh2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row
        'If sh2.Range("A" & j).Value = "" Then
          Set newRow = sh2.ListObjects(1).ListRows.Add '*****  does the command to add the new row have to be indexed?
          sh1.Rows(f.Row).Copy newRow.Range ' sh2.Range("A" & j)
        '  Exit For
        'End If
      'Next
      Set f = r.FindNext(f)
    Loop While f.Address <> cell
  End If

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub



Tables have a built-in Total Row option that you should leverage.  The Table Total Row will always be the last Row.  We can go to the Table Design tab and to add/remove it.
If there is data below the table we need to move it down to make rooms for the new rows.

The formulas should reference the table ranges by name:




Tickets Out of the Rules 2024






Month
Quantity
Percentage


Sep
=SUMPRODUCT((Table1345[Situation] = "Out of the Rules2") * (TEXT(Table1345[Opened], "mmm") = A194))
=IF(B$198 > 0, B194 / B$198, 0)


Oct
=SUMPRODUCT((Table1345[Situation] = "Out of the Rules2") * (TEXT(Table1345[Opened], "mmm") = A195))
=IF(B$198 > 0, B195 / B$198, 0)


Nov
=SUMPRODUCT((Table1345[Situation] = "Out of the Rules2") * (TEXT(Table1345[Opened], "mmm") = A196))
=IF(B$198 > 0, B196 / B$198, 0)


Dec
=SUMPRODUCT((Table1345[Situation] = "Out of the Rules2") * (TEXT(Table1345[Opened], "mmm") = A197))
=IF(B$198 > 0, B197 / B$198, 0)


TOTAL 2024
=SUM(B194:B197)
=B198/SUM(B194:B197)



Read: Wise Owl - Worksheet CodeNames
Create a Mock Workbook
This will create a workbook where everything is named propery.
Sub SetUp()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    With Workbooks.Add
        Set ws = .Worksheets(1)
        
        With ws
            .Name = "Incidentes"
            .[_CodeName] = "wsIncidentes"
            With .Range("A1:F1")
                .Value = Array("Number", "Opened", "Caller", "Setor de Trabalho", "User Description", "Situation")
                .Offset(1).Value = Array("INC7306105", DateSerial(2024, 9, 4) + TimeSerial(3, 17, 0), "Adam Adkins", "Medical", "Student tend health article want brother power guess.", "Out of the Rules2")
                .Offset(2).Value = Array("INC4658553", DateSerial(2024, 9, 4) + TimeSerial(21, 15, 0), "Tanya Jones", "Bonds", "Behind piece well beautiful town serious avoid.", "Closed")
                .Offset(3).Value = Array("INC9324456", DateSerial(2024, 10, 14) + TimeSerial(6, 38, 0), "Brandon King", "Camera", "Class cup yard lead music offer protect.", "Resolved")
                .Offset(4).Value = Array("INC1296631", DateSerial(2024, 11, 25) + TimeSerial(21, 15, 0), "Mr. Jeffrey Henderson", "Retail", "Throughout question fly finally itself accept plant since travel energy protect.", "Out of the Rules2")
                .Offset(5).Value = Array("INC7004093", DateSerial(2024, 12, 2) + TimeSerial(16, 39, 0), "Alyssa Parker", "Occupational", "Administration trial suggest finally past figure win also.", "Escalated")
                .Offset(6).Value = Array("INC5552174", DateSerial(2024, 12, 4) + TimeSerial(3, 31, 0), "Kristin Johnson", "Dancer", "Magazine office analysis local attack change write someone.", "Out of the Rules2")
            End With
            
            .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range("A1").CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = "tblIncidentes"

        End With
        Set ws = .Worksheets.Add
        With ws
            .Name = "Incidentes FR"
            .[_CodeName] = "wsIncidentesFR"
            .Range("A1:F1").Value = Array("Number", "Opened", "Caller", "Setor de Trabalho", "User Description", "Situation")
            .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range("A1").CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = "tblIncidentesFR"
            
            With .ListObjects("tblIncidentesFR")
                .ShowTotals = True
                .TotalsRowRange.Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("Total 2024", "=SUBTOTAL(103,[Opened])")
            End With
            AddHTMLTable .Range("A5")
            '.Range("A5:C5").Merge
            
        End With
        
    End With
End Sub

Sub AddHTMLTable(Cell As Range)
    Dim Data(35)
    Data(0) = "<table border=""1""><Caption>Tickets Out of the Rules 2024</Caption>"
    Data(1) = "<thead>"
    Data(2) = "<tr>"
    Data(3) = "<th>Month</th>"
    Data(4) = "<th>Quantity Formula</th>"
    Data(5) = "<th>Percentage Formula</th>"
    Data(6) = "</tr>"
    Data(7) = "</thead>"
    Data(8) = "<tbody>"
    Data(9) = "<tr>"
    Data(10) = "<td>Sep</td>"
    Data(11) = "<td>=SUMPRODUCT((tblIncidentes[Situation] = ""Out of the Rules2"") * (TEXT(tblIncidentes[Opened], ""mmm"") = A7))</td>"
    Data(12) = "<td>=IF($B$11 > 0, B7 / $B$11, 0)</td>"
    Data(13) = "</tr>"
    Data(14) = "<tr>"
    Data(15) = "<td>Oct</td>"
    Data(16) = "<td>=SUMPRODUCT((tblIncidentes[Situation] = ""Out of the Rules2"") * (TEXT(tblIncidentes[Opened], ""mmm"") = A8))</td>"
    Data(17) = "<td>=IF($B$11 > 0, B8 / $B$11, 0)</td>"
    Data(18) = "</tr>"
    Data(19) = "<tr>"
    Data(20) = "<td>Nov</td>"
    Data(21) = "<td>=SUMPRODUCT((tblIncidentes[Situation] = ""Out of the Rules2"") * (TEXT(tblIncidentes[Opened], ""mmm"") = A9))</td>"
    Data(22) = "<td>=IF($B$11 > 0, B9 / $B$11, 0)</td>"
    Data(23) = "</tr>"
    Data(24) = "<tr>"
    Data(25) = "<td>Dec</td>"
    Data(26) = "<td>=SUMPRODUCT((tblIncidentes[Situation] = ""Out of the Rules2"") * (TEXT(tblIncidentes[Opened], ""mmm"") = A10))</td>"
    Data(27) = "<td>=IF($B$11 > 0, B10 / $B$11, 0)</td>"
    Data(28) = "</tr>"
    Data(29) = "<tr>"
    Data(30) = "<td>TOTAL 2024</td>"
    Data(31) = "<td>=SUM(B194:B197)</td>"
    Data(32) = "<td>=B198/SUM(B7:B10)</td>"
    Data(33) = "</tr>"
    Data(34) = "</tbody>"
    Data(35) = "</table>"
    With CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
       .SetText Join(Data, vbNewLine)
        .PutInClipBoard
    End With
    Cell.PasteSpecial
End Sub


Private Sub IncidentesFR_Open()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wsIncidentes As Worksheet, wsIncidentesFR As Worksheet
  
    Set wsIncidentes = Worksheets("Incidentes")
    Set wsIncidentesFR = Worksheets("Incidentes FR")
  
    Dim tblIncidentes As ListObject, tblIncidentesFR As ListObject
    Set tblIncidentes = wsIncidentes.ListObjects(1)
    Set tblIncidentesFR = wsIncidentesFR.ListObjects(1)
    
    Dim SituationColumn As Range
    Set SituationColumn = tblIncidentes.ListColumns("Situation").DataBodyRange
    

    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To tblIncidentes.ListRows.Count
        If SituationColumn(r).Value = "Out of the Rules2" Then
            Rem We need to make room for the new row
            Rem We insert a row above the summaray tabe
            tblIncidentesFR.Range.End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Resize(, 6).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            
            Dim NewRow As Range
            Set NewRow = tblIncidentesFR.ListRows.Add.Range
            tblIncidentes.ListRows(r).Range.Copy NewRow
        End If
   
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Code to Run in the ock Workbook
Here I refactored the code to run with the proper setup:
Function tblIncidentes() As ListObject
    Set tblIncidentes = wsIncidentes.ListObjects("tblIncidentes")
End Function

Function tblIncidentesFR() As ListObject
    Set tblIncidentesFR = wsIncidentesFR.ListObjects("tblIncidentesFR")
End Function

Private Sub IncidentesFR_Open()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim SituationColumn As Range
    Set SituationColumn = tblIncidentes.ListColumns("Situation").DataBodyRange
    
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To tblIncidentes.ListRows.Count
        If SituationColumn(r).Value = "Out of the Rules2" Then
            Rem We need to make room for the new row
            Rem We insert a row above the summaray tabe
            tblIncidentesFR.Range.End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Resize(, 6).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            
            Dim NewRow As Range
            Set NewRow = tblIncidentesFR.ListRows.Add.Range
            tblIncidentes.ListRows(r).Range.Copy NewRow
        End If
   
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


thaks... I also used your code and it worked!
